# Cannot add or change records

Tags: ms-access, inheritance

I'm designing a database structure wherein I like to apply the concept of **inheritance**.
There's a `base tables` and `derived tables` in which the relationship is **one-to-one**. I'm quite new as of how could this be achieved and how the data are to be fed to the tables because I'm getting errors I can't solved.

I'm wondering if I'm on the right track doing this.

Here's the design view of the database:

[image]

I get the error of

```
You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in the table **PatientRegular**
```

In which case the table I'm on currently working?

And the relationship view:

[image]

What is the right way to do that? I want to inherit all those similar fields to another table?

**Update**

Either way, I cannot also insert new data in the base table (I must be in a wrong track)

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't those relationships be one to many as a patient could have multiple check-ups and operations?

Comment: @JamesAnderson Uhh can you elaborate more? Does that means that the `derived` tables will not have a `primary key` then?

Comment: No they can and should have a Primary Key. What I mean is 1 Patient can have many operations. This means they could have many records in the operations table so the relationship should be 1 to many not 1 to 1.

Comment: @JamesAnderson Uhm do I need to create another field to refer, to make the `one to many`?

Comment: Yes each table other than the patient table will need it's on ID column which will be the Primary key of that table. For example the Operation table would have OperationID. This keeps each operation record unique. You will join the tables on the PatientID still.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, as James Anderson suggests, one-to-one relationships are not the way to do it. One patient may be checked up, operated on, discharged etc., more than once. The tables you have now should be renamed as follows and given their own unique ID primary keys to better represent what they are trying to model:

- `PatientRegular` to `Regular`
- `PatientDischarge` to `Discharge`
- `PatientOperate` to `Operation`
- `PatientCheckup` to `Checkup`

They should still retain their `PatientID` columns but those columns should become foreign key reference columns back to the `PatientID` column in the `Patient` table. In other words, you will have one-to-many relationships between:

- `Patient` to `Regular`
- `Patient` to `Discharge`
- `Patient` to `Operation`
- `Patient` to `Checkup`